# How can this be solved?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For $x$, $y$ and $z$, which are positive integers, $xy + 2x + 3y = 2$ and $yz + 4y + 3z = 52$. Find the value of: $$x + y + z + xy + xz + yz + xyz$$ How could this be solved?

Comment: Did you mean only integers or positive integers?

Comment: There may be a typo in the first equation, there are no **positive** $x,y$ satisfying it.

Comment: non-negative integers

Comment: Note that the target function is $(1+x)(1+y)(1+z)-1$

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

$$(2+y)(3+x)=2+6$$

$$(3+y)(4+z)=52+12$$

Comment: No i still don't get it.

Comment: @user153671, $x$ is integer, so will be $3+x\implies (2+y)$ must divide $2+6=8$ Check which value(s) of $y$ keep(s) $z$ an integer

Comment: I have two solutions in integers, none in non-negative integers.